# Как вывести в {custom номер текущей категории DLE

Tags: php, dle

В engine/main.php 
Такой код

```html
$tpl->set('{category-id}',$cat_info[$category_id]['id']);
```

Но в custom он не работает

Answer (score 0):

Как выводите в custom? И где?

И эту строчку Вы сами вставили? Если да, то куда. Обычно надо ставить перед загрузкой самого шаблона

`$tpl->set('{category-id}',$cat_info[$category_id]['id']);`

Comment: для уточнений есть комментарии под вопросом

Comment: Может не до загрузки шаблона, а до парсера тегов?